# How are C++ macros matched？there is a question about the number of macro parameters

Tags: c++, macros

I read like this

```
#define num(_5, _4, _3, _2, _1, N, ...) N

...

int num_macro_parameters = num(a, b, _5, _4, _3, _2, _1);
```

Why can `num(a, b, _5, _4, _3, _2, _1)` be recognized by macros above?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Also you should decide which language you are asking about and tag accordingly.

Comment: Put that code in a source file, and run through the preprocessor to look at the generated output.

Comment: Why not? `num` expects at least 7 arguments and such number is provided. So where are you seeing a problem? Please provide [mcve] and express your doubts explicitly.

Comment: ohh，thanks，I think I misunderstood the parameters before

Comment: The **name** of an argument doesn't determine what **value** can be passed to it. The `_5` in the macro definition has nothing to do with the `_5` in the macro invocation.

Comment: thanks！I understand it！

Comment: You might also try something like `int num_macro_parameters = num(a, b, c, d, e, f, g);` in the preprocessor to see what happens, It might help you understand macros a little better.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.